# ellipsoid and paraboloid relation

Tags: opengl, graphics, computational-geometry

My task was to create a paraboloid and a ellipsoid using c++ with *opengl*.
I implemented paraboloid as set of points that's distance from the focal point and the distance from the plane is the same. After running the compiler, I got something that looked like an ellipsoid.

The mistake was that accidentally I put a multiplier (that was around 1.1) at the distance from focal point. 
So I got the equation `|Q-F|*1.1=|Q-P|` , where `Q` is the point to be decided whether part of the ellipse/paraboloid, `F` is the focal point, `P` is point projected from `F` to the plane(`P->F` vector is normalvector of the plane this way). 

After correcting the equation to `|Q-F|=|Q-P|`, i got a paraboloid, as expected. When I changed the equation to `(|Q-F|*m=|Q-P| ,m>1)` I got an ellipsoid. 
Is this equation really an ellipsoid?

Comment: Isn´t that math? Not programming.

Comment: Can you show your code? Images showing what doesn't work and describing what you expect instead would be great.

Comment: If I am remembering correctly then ellipsoid is `|Q-F1|+|Q-F2|=c` where c is constant so I don't think your case is ellipsoid (see no way to convert it to this equation) you can try to fit your object with ellipsoid and compute sum off abs distances to see the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to consider 2D case (because paraboloid and ellipsoid could be formed by rotation).
Let's points in set have distances L to OY axis and distances R to F point, and  distance's ratio is coefficient m:

```
L * m =  R
```

Let's `m^2 = k`

```
k * L^2 = R^2
k * X^2 = Y^2 + (X - F)^2
X^2 * (k-1) + 2 * X * F - F^2 = Y^2
```

when k = 1 then

```
Y^2 = 2* F * (X - F/2)
```

This is canonical equaition of parabola, shifted by F/2

when `k > 1, k-1 = p > 0`,  then

```
X^2 + 2 * X * F / p - Y^2 / p = F^2 / p
```

This is hyperbola

when `k < 1, 1 - k = p > 0`, then

```
-p * X^2 - 2 * X * F + Y^2 + F^2 = 0
(X - F/P)^2 + Y^2/p = F^2/p^2*(1-p)
```

If there are no mistakes in my calculations, then this is ellipse, centered in `Xc = F/p`, with semiaxes `F*Sqrt(1-p)/p` and `F * Sqrt((1-p)/p)`

[image]